# Iterate through custom cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to iterate through cells in my UITableView that contains cells of custom class "tempCell", however, I get an error `type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

```
let paths = tableView_sign_in.visibleCells()
for cell: tempCell in paths  {  // type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    cell.textfield.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to 'if let' the customCell

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCell() {
   if let customCell = cell as? TempCell {
      customCell.textField.enabled = false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate, you can cast the cells to your custom type using a optional binding (`if let`) and a conditional downcast (`as?`):

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells() {
    if let customCell as? TempCell {
        customCell.textField.enabled = false
    }
}
```